# Qt OLEAUT32.DLL, COMDLG32.DLL not registered?

Tags: xml, qt, windows-10, lib, comdlg32

I'm developing a new software in Qt but since a few days I get some confusing error messages when I **run** the project:

```
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!75FEEF12: (caller: 75FEE58F) ReturnHr(1) tid(10a0) 8002801D Bibliothek nicht registriert.
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!75FEEF12: (caller: 75FEE58F) ReturnHr(2) tid(10a0) 8002801D Bibliothek nicht registriert.
```

After I try to **open** an XML file with a QFileDialog a new error message appears:

```
shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(14267)\COMDLG32.DLL!76FC7BED: (caller: 76FF686C) ReturnHr(1) tid(10a0) 80004005 Unbekannter Fehler
    CallContext:[\PickerModalLoop]
```

I really don't know how to fix the problem, maybe it exists because of a new windows10 update?

Both of the messages won't crash the program. The first message appears every time I run project, the second only appears when openening an XML file, this also leads to not being able to work with the program because I need to open that XML file. I'm pretty sure the problem does not come in with a code problem.

Does anyone can help me? I reinstalled Qt, the problem still exists.

Comment: Please write your question in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Comment: after changing the language to english in Qt, the error message still appears in german, i hope its ok

Comment: reinstall QT, maybe here some information got corrupted

Comment: Providing a [mcve] is always useful.

Comment: According to https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2967 , not Qt-related.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, except mine is in English: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579720/qt-widget-application-library-not-registered-error

Comment: Since this question was also asked very recently it leads me to believe this may be due to a Windows update. I have Windows 10 and I installed updates last night.

Comment: I also did a reinstall of Qt, and the problem still persists.

Comment: I am facing the same problem (Win10, x64 building with Qt5.5, MSVC2013, x32): `mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!76AC5072: (caller: 76ACFE4F) ReturnHr(1) tid(250) 8002801D Library not registered.` appears just before new window shows after calling `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`. I was able to supress the problem using the `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` option, but then the Open File window do not have the fully native look.

Comment: Why is this question closed? I have same problem. like @MaciekS. Appearing when I trying to call QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()

Comment: @GeneCode, has `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` solved your problem?

Comment: @MaciekS i'll try it soon and reply here.