# Qt Widget Application "Library not registered" error

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, com

I've just recently started out with Qt and created a simple Qt Widgets application.  When I build and run the application (even if I make a fresh project with no new code in it) I get the following error messages:

> mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!74445072: (caller: 7444FE4F) ReturnHr(1) tid(188) 8002801D Library not registered.
>   mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!74445072: (caller: 7444FE4F) ReturnHr(2) tid(188) 8002801D Library not registered.

My Qt install and Windows are both up to date. I've been searching for a solution for a couple hours now and I can't find anything even remotely relevant to the problem online... Has anyone else anywhere had a similar issue?

**Update:**

I just completely removed Qt from my PC and did a fresh install and I am still getting the same messages.

Comment: The question is not really about Qt but the app relies on COM object in the system and not gracefully checks/warns on it presence/absence/registration of its library in the system. The question is hardly possibly to answer like that. You need to find an exact COM object the app relies on. Correct tags are COM/Windows

Comment: @AlexanderVX How would I go about doing that? All I have to work with here is that really cryptic error message. I'm totally lost. I've updated the tags to slightly better reflect the issue

Comment: As far as I can tell from Google I may have an issue in my Windows registry? If that's the case the only way to reset it seems to be a reinstall of Windows, but I'm really hoping to avoid that...

Comment: You say you created it? What part of code does that COM call?

Comment: @AlexanderVX, I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you're asking. All I did to get this error was create a Qt Project through the Qt IDE. When I build and run the project I get these messages. I didn't really do anything strange. I don't even really know what a COM is. :(

Comment: I have created many apps with Qt and never seen anything like that right away before the other code written/added. Try to examine the executable with http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find how come there is such dependence.

Comment: Okay I will look into that. I have a feeling my registry may have something corrupt in it though... I hope that's not the case.

Comment: That was even asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496701/qt-oleaut32-dll-comdlg32-dll-not-registered

Comment: @AlexanderVX Yes, it looks like that is probably the same issue... unfortunately that post does not seem to have any helpful answers to it.

Comment: @AlexanderVX That question looks like it was also asked very recently and they are also on Windows 10. That leads me to believe that this may be caused by a recent Windows 10 update. I installed updates last night and today is the first time I have noticed this issue. (Although I hadn't used Qt much before so I wasn't sure if this issue was new or not.)

Comment: See, nothing till now tells us COM is involved with Qt until we start doing that by hand.

Comment: I guess you see this in the output window of the debugger. It seems that someone at MS turned the debug reporting on for Windows DLL's. Expect a bounce if you complain about it on MS forums:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/152917/uwp-c-how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-output-message-onec.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh. This problem wrecked my sunday.

I'm on QT 5.9.1, Windows 10, Surface Book.

I tried reinstalling windows, didn't work. I tried reinstalling Microsoft Runtime, didn't work. Reinstalled QT in a million different ways, didn't work.

So I was on the latest updates, and checked my oleaut32.dll version - 1.1.15063.0. According to an old forum post I found around, this error can be caused by the application requesting a newer version of oleaut32.dll than you have. So I jumped onto the insider preview versions (picking the slow ring) and was upgraded to release 10.0.16251 which also upgraded my oleaut32.dll. Fixed it, no error anymore. QT creator finally works.

I guess QT requires you to be on beta windows now?

Comment: LOL, that's ridiculous. Since it still seems to compile and work with the warning and it looks like it will be fixed with a future Windows update I guess I'll suffer through seeing the warnings a little longer...

Comment: I get this error message with Win32 API's MessageBox() on latest Windows!!

Comment: I'm getting this error message in VS 2022 running on Windows 10. for a. .NET Framework 4.8 desktop application.

Comment: yep, also seeing this, Qt 5.15

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you receive a blank white screen when attempting to open a Qt GUI app while this issue was unresolved?